# Does a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ always lift to a continuous map $f': X' \to Y$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ be path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply connected. Let $X'$ be the universal covering space of $X$. Is it true that a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ always lifts to a continuous map $f': X' \to Y$ such that all the points in a fibre of $X$ map to the same point $f(x)$?

Comment: To be clear, by "all the points in a fibre of X map to the same point f(x)" you mean that all the points in any fiber of the map $X'\to X$ (over a point $x\in X$) are sent to $f(x)$ by $f'$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though this isn't usually called lifting.  If $p:X'\to X$ is the covering map, then you just define $f'$ to be the composition $f\circ p$.

"Lifting" normally refers to the situation where your maps are going in the other direction, so the existence of a map is nontrivial (you can't just get the map by composing).  That is, if you have a map $g:Y\to X$, a lifting of $g$ to $X'$ is a map $g':Y\to X'$ such that $g=p\circ g'$.